# Angular 9 How to refresh @Input data in Child Component

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

I have a child component that displays a result in mat-table which source is from parent component as @Input.

I am using a dialog component in the child to edit rows in the mat-table. Then the row value is updated in the database.

But the problem is my @Input data is not updated, so I tried creating new datasource, onChangedetector but table is not updated. Once I refresh the page, the table updates because I get new data as @Input.

So my question is there anyway to update the @Input data in child component (i.e. refresh parent component so that it sends new input data after getting updated from the database)

I can think one way to do is update the @input data by calling the service that is used by parent component in the child...

Is there any better solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago, I made this code, using @Input and  @Output. Through those decorators you could pass values between parent and child compoents. In this example if there is **some change in the input** from the parent component the **set month fucntion** is executed again.

In order to notice that a change is made in child you use the emit function from your @Output.

Hope that helps you with your problem. Or at least give you some Idea of how to improve it.

```
  @Input() 
  set month(data:any) {
    // data = {year: 2020, month: 4}
    this.GenerateDays(data.year, data.month); // 2019/Agosto (2019, 7) Ene=0
  }

  @Output() onDayChange = new EventEmitter();    

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  private GenerateDays (year:number, month:number) {
    // Logic to Generate Days           
  }

  public SelectDay (id:number) {    
    this.selectedDay = id;
    this.onDayChange.emit(this.selectedDay);
  }
```